# How to set up virtual users in vsftpd?

Tags: linux, users, vsftpd

I've read this tutorial: http://howto.gumph.org/content/setup-virtual-users-and-directories-in-vsftpd/
My configuration is as follow:

```
---vsftpd.conf---
listen=YES
anonymous_enable=NO
local_enable=YES
virtual_use_local_privs=YES
write_enable=YES
connect_from_port_20=YES
pam_service_name=vsftpd
guest_enable=YES
user_sub_token=$USER
local_root=/var/www/sites/$USER
chroot_local_user=YES
hide_ids=YES

---/etc/pam.d/vsftpd---
auth    required pam_pwdfile.so pwdfile /etc/vsftpd/passwd
account required pam_permit.so
```

I created file **/etc/vsftpd/passwd** and added users using htaccess.
I tried to login but it didn't work:

```
ftp 127.0.0.1
Connected to 127.0.0.1 (127.0.0.1).
220 vsFTPd 2.3.5+ (ext.1) ready...
Name (127.0.0.1:root): user1
331 Please specify the password.
Password:
530 Permission denied.
Login failed.
```

Everything seems fine accept the permission denied thing. How can I fix this?

Answer (score 1):

Maybe you forgot to give your ftp user read/write permission to /var/www/sites/$user ?

Try following this guide for setting up the server:
http://www.noob2geek.com/linux/setup-vsftpd-debian-ubuntu/

I have used it a couple of months ago with good results.